# On Page layout "required" is not working for lighting

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have ticked one field "Required" in Page layout, Its fine on classic but on lighting the same field is not mandatory. Any Idea why?
Lighting -https://www.screencast.com/t/5id0trFjg
Classic- https://www.screencast.com/t/VdPb2WW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue and is being reviewed by the Salesforce team.

Here is the link to the reported issue - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYubQAG